# Can I change Ubuntu Kylin to the normal version?

Tags: kylin

I installed Ubuntu Kylin by mistake, the language is messed up and the layout and appearance is completely different from the normal version. Is there a way to convert it post installation?

Comment: If you only just installed, it's just as easy to reinstall it...